# Getter return type is any when object has a method and is passed through generic function

Tags: typescript

I have the following code, where my getter's return type is `any` despite the real return type being obvious. There's some additional functions to trigger this behavior:

```
// This is required for repro
const wrapperFunction = <T>(obj: T) => obj;

const store = wrapperFunction({
  value: 'Super max',

  get simpleGetter() {
    return this.value;
  },

  // This is required for repro
  bark() {
    console.log('WUF');
  },
});

// This is any
const val = store.simpleGetter;
// This logs "Super max"
console.log(val);
```

Here's link to TypeScript playground: [Full repro](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=99&jsx=0&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=false#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdTqATgUwI4FdqoCagGYD2SyKADkoQLABQAxoQHawAuoA7kgIZlkpIAxDIzotoTUAF5QAHnAA+ABSEARgCsAXBACUU+aFVqA3LVoNmbVsRRSO3XvyEixTRQG9aoUADcuAGwwULQByAGUMPhIAWy4AD2CAGlMaLwBzFEtoKLI-FABxDJZ+RV0PFK9SFgwkRlAWGFgAOl8AlBNygF8kmk9QEAgGhHhUTGwUPCISVApqcpUuJABrEtAyitBzWEJcxr9CVMVggHUAVQFg7XavLtoOy+T+qERELkYATzMmVh9-WytURqwLI5fKFfjtR6DPapeAAInCkVAMVisM+zG2KF2+0ULXuNCAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a TypeScript bug: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49511

Easiest workaround is to write the return type manually or assign the object to a variable before passing it to generic function:

```
// This is required for repro
const wrapperFunction = <T>(obj: T) => obj;

const storeObj = {
  value: 'Super max',

  get simpleGetter() {
    return this.value;
  },

  // This is required for repro
  bark() {
    console.log('WUF');
  },
};
const store = wrapperFunction(storeObj);

// This is string now
const val = store.simpleGetter;
```